# Use one quicksight dashboard (created from one analysis) for different data sets

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a multi-user website and each user has own data which I can store on s3.
I want to integrate(embed) QuickSight to my website, in that way so each user able to see own data.
I want to have one analysis to be able to modify if for all users.

---

Are there some recommendations on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to add the user's identifier (email, name, generated ID, whatever) to each row that belongs to them in the S3 data. I'm kind of assuming that you are storing the data in a tabular format (e.g. CSV) but let me know if I'm wrong. So let's assume you added this user identifier as a new column called `userId`.

Secondly, you will need to generate a [manifest file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html) that points to all of your users' S3 files.

Then, create a new data set, pointing to that manifest.

Then, you will need to create another new data set that ties a QuickSight `UserName` to the new `userId` column you have added. You will need to maintain this data set somehow, but fortunately the QuickSight `UserName` has a pattern to it (something like `embed_role\user_name`).

An example of this new data set might look like

```
UserName,userId
your_embed_role\user3479125,user3479125
```

Once you have this data set you can attach it to the S3 data set created earlier as [row-level-security](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/restrict-access-to-a-data-set-using-row-level-security.html) (RLS). You can think of QuickSight as performing an inner join on `userId` between the RLS data set and the actual visual data set, thus limiting the data to the given `UserName`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, implemented unique row id approach a week ago